# Theme field output

Tags: 7, entities, theming

I have a field called field_news_title. I want to override its output so I created a file called field--field-news-title.tpl.php in my_theme/templates folder but it's not working.
I tried also to put the file in my_theme root dir and in news content type dir.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cleared cache ?

Comment: Yes, cache clear from admin interface.

Comment: I also tried to override the field.tpl.php but with no success.

Comment: field--field-news-title.tpl.php is always an override of field.tpl.php. Looks like your theme template name is correct as per http://drupal.org/node/1089656 though

Comment: Can you override anything? What about block, node etc?

Comment: Yes, I can override node, block, region, page, node--[content-type], views-exposed-form--[content-type], but when I create the field--field-news-title.tpl.php I can't see any change. I also tried to override the mytheme_field() hook and mytheme_preprocess_field() hook but nothing seems to happen. Cache cleared from Admin interface and with drush cc all command.

Answer (score 2):

I tried with field name  **field_article_current_rating** and I have created the template file called **field--field_article_current_rating.tpl.php** and it is working.

So I think in your case you should try **field--field_news_title.tpl.php**

And one more thing I put this file in

> /sites/all/themes/theme_name/templates

folder, as I am using Omega subtheme.

Comment: I have created a sub-theme of Drupal Twitter Bootstrap theme. Is it possible that the problem is coming from TB theme?

Comment: Not at all. Simply you have to create a tpl and put with all tpls like node.tpl.php, page.tpl.php etc.