# How to theme field for many views in drupal 7?

Tags: views, entities, theming

I want to theme `field--uc-product-image.tpl.php` for two views. How to do this?

Is Drupal have theme like `view1-field--uc-product-image.tpl.php` ?

Comment: Possible Duplicates:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45767/theme-field-output
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914220/how-to-theme-views-fields-in-drupal-7-correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use template file, you can do that with:
 **views-view--[view name]--[display].tpl.php**

If your view name is "**My product Image**" and display is "**block**"

view mashine name will be: "**my_product_image**"

and your template file will be:

**views-view--my-product-image--block.tpl.php**

in this file you can get your fields in that way:

```
$fields = $view->style_plugin->rendered_fields; // fields array
```

and then customize fields with the foreach loop.

**Example:**

```
<?php foreach ($fields as $delta => $item): ?>
    <?php if ($item['uri']) : ?>
        <img src="<?php print $item['uri']; ?>" alt="" class="pull-left">
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Of course there are several ways to custom your image field. In this example I assuming that you need to do that in view template file.